# array of strings or a string enums in JSDoc

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I have the following function which takes

- yellow.
- green.
- orange.

```js
function colorize (givenArg){
  return givenArg
}
```

where `givenArg` could be a string or an array of strings.

I want to define the enums for the `givenArg` argument, but how?

```js
/**
* @param {['green', 'yellow', 'orange']} givenArg
*/
function colorize (givenArg){
  return givenArg
}
```

Currently, this only works for arrays, but how to make it work with both, an array of the strings, or a single string, without having to re-write yellow, green and orange two times?

Comment: `givenArg : ('green' | 'yellow' | 'orange)[] | 'green' | 'yellow' | 'orange'`

Comment: @Konrad yes, you repeated them twice, that's what I want to avoid

Comment: `type X  =  'green' | 'yellow' | 'orange'` then `givenArg: X | X[]`

Comment: @Konrad, this is typescript, I'm writing vanilla JavaScript, so I need jsDoc

Comment: Next time don't add `typescript` tag if you don't use it :)

Answer (score 3):

In JsDoc, you can use the [@typedef](https://jsdoc.app/tags-typedef.html) tag as follow:

```
/** @typedef {'green' | 'yellow' | 'orange'} X */

/** @typedef {X | X[]} ColorizeParam */

/**
 * @param {ColorizeParam} givenArg
 */
function colorize(givenArg) { }
```

You may skip the intermediate step and directly type `@param {X | X[]} givenArg` if you want.
Based on @Konrad's answer.